# Referencing external JAR from JavaFX Project

Tags: javafx, java-module

I'm trying to reference a set of APIs from my JavaFX project:

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

These APIs are available in this dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
     <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Therefore, I have added the jakarta.ws.rs-api in my project's module-info.java :

```
module com.example.javafx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;

    //External API
    requires jakarta.ws.rs-api;

    opens com.example.javafx to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.javafx;
}
```

However, it seems incorrect: "Module directive expected" for "jakarta.ws.rs-api".
Should I use a different format to specify the external dependency?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must use the module name after `requires`.
The dash is not a allowed character for module names, just like for package name.

You can obtain the name of a module bundled in a jar file with:

```sh
jar --describe-module --file jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.1.0.jar
```

which gives `jakarta.ws.rs`

Comment: You can also find the [`module-info.java` in the source code](https://github.com/jakartaee/rest/blob/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/module-info.java) if you know where to look.